# SQL Group By and Order -- retrieve detail for most recent entries in table

Tags: sql, group-by, mariadb, sql-order-by

I want to Make a SQL Query that returns the newest Entry for each bot_id.

My current request looks like this, but it ALWAYS returns the first Entry. DESC & ASC don't make any difference:

```sql
SELECT bot_id, id
FROM t_request_history
GROUP BY bot_id
ORDER BY request_time DESC
```

The Tables looks like this:

### t_request_history

| id | bot_id | request | response | error | request_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | usr_e74ae42b-080c-48e0-9e6c | a | a | 0 | 2021-09-16 23:37:10 |
| 2 | usr_e74ae42b-080c-48e0-9e6c | a | a | 1 | 2021-09-16 23:37:35 |
| 3 | usr_e74ae42b-080c-48e0-9e6c | a | a | 1 | 2021-09-16 23:43:20 |
| 4 | delete | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2021-09-16 23:44:21 |
| 5 | delete | 1 | 1 | 0 | 2021-09-16 23:44:32 |
| 6 | delete | 1 | 1 | 0 | 2021-09-16 23:44:41 |

### Wanted Result

| bot_id | id |
| --- | --- |
| delete | 6 |
| usr_e74ae42b-080c-48e0-9e6c | 3 |

### Actual Result

| bot_id | id |
| --- | --- |
| delete | 4 |
| usr_e74ae42b-080c-48e0-9e6c | 1 |

Is there any way to make this query work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `id` values go up with time. That is, it looks like newer entries in your table have higher `id` values than older entries.  If this is true,

```sql
SELECT bot_id, MAX(id) id
FROM t_request_history
GROUP BY bot_id
```

gets you what you want.

If the `id` values don't go up with time, you have to use a subquery to find the latest time for each bot_id.

```sql
                 SELECT bot_id, MAX(request_time) request_time
                   FROM t_request_history
                  GROUP BY bot_id
```

Then you join that subquery to your table like this:

```sql
SELECT a.bot_id, a.id
  FROM t_request_history a
  JOIN (
                    SELECT bot_id, MAX(request_time) request_time
                      FROM t_request_history
                     GROUP BY bot_id
       ) b   ON a.bot_id = b.bot_id
            AND a.request_time = b.request_time
```

The ON condition of the JOIN chooses just the rows with the latest times from your table.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using a Window/Analytic function

```
SELECT distinct
 bot_id, MAX(request_time) OVER(PARTITION BY bot_id)
FROM t_request_history
;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b8a28f/6)

You could also find more details on the usage @ [MariaDB WindowFunction Max documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/max/)